# How can I use Mandrill on the Firebase hosting?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Is it possible to use the Mandrill service in the firebase hosting? Any example of how configure it?

Answer (score 1):

Though I have not used Mandrill from client side myself (nor do I encourage doing it), here is what I found.

Since, Firebase hosting delivers only static content, you should be able to use Mandrill only if you are willing to use Mandrillapp API from only client side from your JavaScript. You can refer to this answer,
[How to use Mandrillapp API from only client side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19245296/how-to-use-mandrillapp-api-from-only-client-side)

Also, here is some working Mandrill example code, [How to send an email from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/how-to-send-an-email-from-javascript)

and also this, [How to send an email with Mandrill using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29995207/how-to-send-an-email-with-mandrill-using-javascript)

But be careful, since your API is visible to everyone, anyone with bad intent can misuse it.

Hope it helps.